# Displaying a Highchart Line Chart in Mapbox Marker Pop-up

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts, mapbox

My goal is to display two small Highchart line charts (height:100px;) inside of a Mapbox pop-up. I have two divs inside the HTML to hold the charts, which as is shown in the image below appear to take the charts because the axes are showing up just fine.

[image]

The thing that is perplexing me is that the series and markers are not displaying, save for half of the first marker that is split by the y-axis. When inspecting the Highchart element in Chrome, all paths for the markers and series appear to be in the right location and are marked as visibility="visible".

[image]

Has anyone run into a similar issue?

UPDATE: Live Demo - http://jsfiddle.net/calanoue/tf95sLsu/

```
<head lang="en">
<title></title>
</head>
<body>
<div id='map'></div>
<script>
...
</script>
</body>
```

Comment: Could you replicate your example as live demo ?

Comment: Live Demo - http://jsfiddle.net/calanoue/tf95sLsu/

Comment: Have you possibility to initialise chart after open popup (I mean in callback of this function openPopup )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I try with this solution, may it will help you,
 [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/t95x2df7/)

**HTML:**

```
<head lang="en">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id='map'></div>

</body>
```

**CSS:**

```
  body {
       margin: 0;
       padding: 0;
   }
   #map {
       position: absolute;
       top: 0;
       bottom: 0;
       width: 100%;
   }

   .sparkline {
       height: 100px;
       width: 200px;
   }
```

**jQuery:**

```
L.mapbox.accessToken = 'pk.eyJ1IjoibmF1dGlseXRpY3MiLCJhIjoidG5tdktlMCJ9.Ktr2w0QzGrAN2UNtrJJziw';

var map = L.mapbox.map('map', 'nautilytics.icjmd18i').setView([37.8, -96], 4);
var myLayer = L.mapbox.featureLayer().addTo(map);

 var portGeoJSON = {
            "type": "FeatureCollection",
                "features": [{
                "type": "Feature",
                    "geometry": {
                    "type": "Point",
                        "coordinates": [-74.0047538280487, 40.7590498275021]
                },
                    "properties": {
                    "title": "NEW YORK",
                        "est_value": 13639833,
                        "marker-color": "#0000ff",
                        "marker-size": "medium",
                        "marker-symbol": "harbor"
                }
            }]
        };

var lineChartOptions = {
            title: {
                text: null
            },
            legend: {
                enabled: false
            },
            credits: {
                enabled: false
            },
            exporting: {
                enabled: false
            },
            tooltip: {
                backgroundColor: {
                    linearGradient: [0, 0, 0, 60],
                    stops: [
                        [0, '#FFFFFF'],
                        [1, '#E0E0E0']
                    ]
                },
                borderWidth: 1,
                useHTML: true,
                borderColor: '#AAA'
            },
            yAxis: {
                min: 0,
                lineWidth: 1,
                tickWidth: 1,
                title: {
                    text: null
                },
                labels: {
                    style: {
                        'fontSize': '10px'
                    }
                }
            },
            xAxis: {
                type: 'datetime',
                labels: {
                    style: {
                        'fontSize': '10px'
                    }
                }
            },
            plotOptions: {
                series: {
                    cursor: 'pointer',
                    connectNulls: false
                }
            }
        };

myLayer.on('layeradd', function(e) {
    var marker = e.layer,
        feature = marker.feature;


    lineChartOptions.tooltip.formatter = function() {
                var y = "$" + this.y;
                return '<center>' + Highcharts.dateFormat('%b \'%y', new Date(this.x)) + '</center></b><center><b>' + y + '</b></center>';
            };
    lineChartOptions.series = [{
                pointInterval: 24 * 3600 * 1000 * 30.41667,
                pointStart: 1393632000000,
                data: [
                58044, 60871, 29738, null, 804997, 628727, 20678, null,
                100606, 122195, 981459, 39840]
            }];


     // HTML content for pop-up
           var popupContent = '<div id="popup_template">' +
        '<div class="port_header marker-title">' +e.layer.feature.properties.title.toUpperCase() +'</div>' +
        '<div class="est_value marker-title">'+
               'Est. Value: $' + e.layer.feature.properties.est_value
               +'</div>' +
        '<div id="est_value_sparkline" class="sparkline"></div>';


    var container = $('<div id="popup_template"/>');


    container.html( '<div class="port_header marker-title">' +e.layer.feature.properties.title.toUpperCase() +'</div>' +
        '<div class="est_value marker-title">'+
               'Est. Value: $' + e.layer.feature.properties.est_value
               +'</div>' +
        '<div id="est_value_sparkline" class="sparkline"></div>');

// Delegate all event handling for the container itself and its contents to the container
container.find('#est_value_sparkline').highcharts(lineChartOptions);


    marker.bindPopup(container[0]);
});

myLayer.setGeoJSON(portGeoJSON);
```

Comment: Thanks. This does work well. I was just hoping to abstract out the inline HTML to a separate file to keep things tidy, but I guess that's not the best approach for this specific problem.